# JSoup - Extracting the title and price only

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to extract a listing's name and price off eBay sold listings. However, my code below does not seem to work:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=PSA+10+silver+prizm+rookies&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1").get();
            String index = "li#srp-river-results-listing1";
            Elements listings = document.select(index); // Each box contains the deal info
            //System.out.println(listings);
            String listingName = listings.select("h3.s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags").text();
            //for (int j = 0; j < listingName.length() - 1; j++) {
                //if(listingName.charAt(j) == '?') {
                    //System.out.println("This listing is wrong.");
                //}
            }
            System.out.println(listingName);
        }
```

I am able to print the listings, but the the listingName. I suspect that I select the name wrong - but I don't know how to fix it. If I replace

```
String listingName = listings.select("h3.s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags").text();
```

with

```
String listingName = listings.text();
```

It will give me every text within the `li` element, which I don't need - I only need the listings' name and sold price.

Answer (score 0):

I just try the css selector and realized that, instead of `"li#srp-river-results-listing1"`, I should have select `"a.s-item__link > h3"`.